# It is almost too easy

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Whenever she gets stressed out, she smokes. ***And it is almost too
>   easy to stress her out***.

This line is from a sitcom called Brooklyn Nine-Nine

What does the marked phrase mean? I think ıt means she gets stressed out easily but it is somehow strange to me.

Don't we use "it is + too + adjective + to + do something" to imply that you can't do "something" because is too "adjective" ?

For example : Your handwriting is too small to read. (I can't read your handwriting because it is too small.)

I think in the quoted sentence, "almost" somehow make it right this usage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right about the meaning of the construction "too [adj.] to [something]". The pattern in your quoted sentence might look like that construction, but in this case, the phrase "to stress her out" has a different function in the sentence.

"Too" can also be used by itself as a simple adverb modifying an adjective. That is the way it is used here.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too) gives these definitions of "**too**":

> "to an excessive degree"; "to such a degree as to be regrettable".

The phrase "to stress her out" just names the activity that is easy.

So "It is **too easy** to stress her out." just means "Stressing her out is **excessively easy**." (i.e. It goes beyond what is reasonable or acceptable.)

Comment: I automatically thought the other pattern-too [adj.] to [something]. But from the context, you could see that pattern wasn't the case in that sentece. Can I use "so" here? "It is so easy to stress her out."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Yes. "It is **so** easy to stress her out." will carry the same meaning in this context. Purists will point out that "**so** easy" and "**too** easy" aren't always *exactly* the same, but in this conversation about smoking & stress (where we aren't discussing consequences or precise degrees of "easi-ness"), they are interchangeable.